# Max. efficient method of summing parts of an array

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to find a more effective way to perform the task below.

The function is being fed some lists. I need to:

1) Find the sum of the list and store the result in another list prepared especially for that.

2) Remove the first element of the input list

3) Find the sum of the new list and append to the list from STEP 1.

4) Repeat until the input list is empty.

Basically, the code below already does the task, but is inefficient in terms of speed (as I understand, the append method isn't the leanest tool in Python arsenal). What would be a more efficient way of doing this?

```py
def parts_sums(ls):
    sums = []

    if len(ls) == 0:
            sums.append(0)

    while len(ls) > 0:
        sums.append(sum(ls))
        ls.pop(0)

        if len(ls) == 0:
            sums.append(0)

    return sums
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ls.pop(0)` is computationally expensive, since that means that all the remaining elements are shifted one place to the left. For *n* elements, this is thus an *O(n)* operation. Furthermore you each time calculate the entire sum of a sublist, which is again an *O(n)* operation.

We can for example first calculate the sum of the entire list, and then each time subtract an element from that like:

```
def parts_sums(ls):
    total = sum(ls)
    yield total
    for item in ls:
        total -= item
        yield total
```

this gives us:

```
>>> list(parts_sums([1,4,2,5]))
[12, 11, 7, 5, 0]
```

We can calculate the list with a simple *scan* over the list, like:

```
def parts_sums(ls):
    a = 0
    result = [0]
    for e in reversed(ls):
        a += e
        result.append(a)
    result.reverse()
    return result
```

For example:

```
>>> parts_sums([1,4,2,5])
[12, 11, 7, 5, 0]
```

We here thus calculate the cummulative sum array of the reversed list, and then reverse that list, which is functionally the same.

We can also use `numpy` for this:

```
import numpy as np

def parts_sums(iterable):
    return np.hstack((np.flip(np.cumsum(np.flip(iterable))), [0]))
```

for example:

```
>>> parts_sums([1,4,2,5])
array([12, 11,  7,  5,  0])
```

**Performance**

I ran some tests on an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz. If `data` is a list of 10'000 elements, we obtain the following results for 1'000 runs:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: list(parts_sums1(data)), number=1000)
1.5667014829959953
>>> timeit(lambda: parts_sums2(data), number=1000)
1.095261047994427
>>> timeit(lambda: parts_sums3(data), number=1000)
0.5962606709945248
```

for a list `data` with 100'000 elements, we obtain the following results for 100 runs each:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: list(parts_sums1(data)), number=100)
1.6292997589989682
>>> timeit(lambda: parts_sums2(data), number=100)
1.1703664560045581
>>> timeit(lambda: parts_sums3(data), number=100)
0.6373857369981124
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for such a detailed answer.

Comment: Can you please include my version with accumulate in your benchmarks? I have AMD 2400G, maybe that's why its faster...

Comment: @AndrejKesely: well it uses floating points, and probably those are calculated less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

One version with `itertools.accumulate`:

```
from itertools import accumulate
import timeit

l = [1,4,2,5]
i = [*accumulate(reversed(l + [0]))][::-1]

print(i)

l = [*range(10_000)]
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: [*accumulate(reversed(l + [0]))][::-1], number=1000))

l = [*range(100_000)]
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: [*accumulate(reversed(l + [0]))][::-1], number=100))
```

Prints (on AMD 2400G):

```
[12, 11, 7, 5, 0]
0.28572049700596835
0.45740387199475663
```

Edit (using `parts_sums1()` and `parts_sums2()` from accepted answer):

```
0.6355529940046836  # parts_sums1()/10_000 items/1000 iterations
0.7757905749967904  # parts_sums1()/100_000 items/100 iterations 
0.5660922379975091  # parts_sums2()/10_000 items/1000 iterations
0.749676775005355   # parts_sums2()/100_000 items/100 iterations
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) and [`operator.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.sub):

```
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import sub

d = [1,4,2,5]
list(accumulate([sum(d),*d], sub))
#[12, 11, 7, 5, 0]
```

Comparatively this answer this is the fastest and easiest to read:

```
timeit(lambda: list(accumulate([sum(d),*d], sub)), number=1000)
#0.0022647730002063327
timeit(lambda: [*accumulate(reversed(d + [0]))][::-1], number=1000)
#0.005318050000369112
timeit(lambda: np.hstack((np.flip(np.cumsum(np.flip(d))), [0])), number=1000)
#0.024382672000228922
```

The code can be found at this REPL: https://repl.it/repls/ApprehensiveMuffledConfig, But refer to the other answers for more explanation on why these are faster.